# Active Storage Not uploading an image on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I have some APIs which I'm working on and using ActiveStorage for image uploading Everything is working fine locally but when I deploy my app on Heroku other's APIs are fine but when I try to upload an image it throws a 500 error.

My storage.yml

```yaml
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
S3:
  service: BetterS3
  root: 'directory'
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: 'abc'
  secret_access_key: 'abc'
  region: 'xyz'
  bucket: 'xyz'
```

I also add these lines to my production.rb & staging.rb

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.active_storage.service = :amazon
end
```

I also install Active storage and install

```rb
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1'
```

Note: I have a dockerized app but I have not pushed the image on Heroku but my app I'm not sure it was just because my gem was not properly uploaded on Heroku maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you tell us what error are you facing? The exact error name/class will help a lot to debug and the version for gems installed will also help.

Comment: actually, I'm hitting my APIs from postman when I upload an image it gives me internal server error status: 500
    @user.image.attach(params[:image])
this code works fine locally & here is the activestorage gem 
aws-sdk-s3 (1.86.0, 1.83.0)

Comment: Thankyou I was facing this problem because of sidekiq

Comment: how did you fix this issue?

Comment: unfortunately, it has been 2 years, and I'm not sure how I fixed this may be it was some configuration issues  or S3 issue